Stability of Hölder constants of frozen Itô stochastic integrals
$
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\TT}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\EE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\FF}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\PPP}{\mathscr{P}}
\newcommand{\KKK}{\mathscr{K}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
$
We fix $T \in (0, \infty)$ and let $\TT$ be the interval $[0, T]$. Let $\sigma : \TT \times \RR^d \to \RR^d \otimes \RR^m$ be measurable. Let $a := \sigma \sigma^\top$. For simplicity, we denote $\sigma_t(x) := \sigma (t, x)$ and $a_t(x) := a (t, x)$. We assume there exist constants $C>0, 0 < \beta < 1$ such that for $t \in \TT$ and $x, y \in \RR^d$:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{C} |y|^2 \le \langle a_t (x) y, y \rangle & \le C |y|^2,  \label{main_assmpt1:ineq1} \\
|\sigma_t (x) - \sigma_t (y)| &\le C |x-y|^\beta. \label{main_assmpt1:ineq2}
\end{align}
Let $(B_t, t \ge 0)$ be a $m$-dimensional Brownian motion and $\FF := (\mathcal F_t, t \ge 0)$ an admissible filtration on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \PP)$. Let $X_0 : \Omega \to \RR^d$ be a $\mathcal F_0$-measurable random variable that admits a probability density function (p.d.f.) denoted by $\ell_0$. Let
$$
X_t := X_0 + \int_0^t \sigma(s, X_0) \diff B_s,
\quad t \in \TT.
$$
From this answer, each $X_t$ admits a p.d.f. denoted by $\ell_t$. We assume that $\ell_0$ belongs to the Hölder space $C^\alpha_b (\RR^d)$ for some $\alpha \in (0, \beta)$.

Is it true that
$$
\sup_{t \in \TT} \sup_{\substack{x,y \in \RR^d \\0 <|x-y| \le 1}} \frac{|\ell_t (x) - \ell_t (y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} < \infty \, ?
$$

Thank you so much for your elaboration.
